# Displaying point data that is close together using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, arcgis-pro, display

I am using ArcGIS Pro to display point data on a map. Each of these points need to be displayed with clearly visible symbols. However, some of them sit very close together, and when displaying on a printed map, they appear as a collective black blob, rather than individual symbols. When I make them small enough that they are separate points, they appear only as tiny dots, not as unique symbols.

How can I best display these points?

Is annotating the symbol itself an option? (as an aside, I do have two inset maps to display the busiest areas, but this is still a problem on the rest of the map).

Answer (score 1):

There are two basic methods for displaying points that are too close together.

The first method is *clustering*. This method combines nearby points into a single symbol. The symbol often includes a number, which shows how many points have been combined. Here's a blog post about using point clustering symbology:

https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/mapping/mapping/clustering-in-arcgis-online-enables-data-exploration-september-2017/

The other method is *displacement* or *dispersal*. The points are rearranged so they can all be seen. Here's a blog post about using "disperse marker" tool:

https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/product/mapping/how-to-scatter-stacked-or-clustered-marker-symbols-for-point-features/